# How to get multiple textfield reference in UITableViewCell when multiple table in one view controller?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitextfield

I have a 3 table in one view controller and each table one cell.

and in the cell multiple textField so i want to get that textField reference in shouldChangeCharacter method??

so how can i get particular tableCell particular textfield??

Answer (score 1):

When you dequeue the cell, in `cellForRowAt`

1- access your `UITextField` and give it a tag .  (`cell.textField.tag = 0`)
2- set its delegate to self .  (`cell.textField.delegate = self`)
3- implement the required delegate and implement your function check on the tag then do what you want.

now inside the `shouldChangeCharacter`  function  check the `UITextField` tag.

**Heads up**:

since you dynamically set the delegate and tag of those `UITextField` don't set the tags statically like the example above, preferred to be something like `indexPath.row`.

**The delegate** : `UITextFieldDelegate` .
**Keep in mind** : Tags are not unique identifiers, all the `UITextField`'s with shared tags can be treated they are the same.

Comment: ya you are right but when i have a multiple textfield in multiple cell then how can i set tag and utilize??

Comment: what are you trying to achieve i might be able to help

Comment: in worst case scenario you can statically define a set of tags for each one of them,